# Count the frequency of n-grams in a random Wikipedia corpus

Tags: python, performance, wikipedia

This code counts the frequency of n-grams in a random Wikipedia corpus, as of now, it downloads everything, than performs all the counting. In your opinion is there a way to perform downloading and counting simultaneously while keeping the code reasonably simple to improve the performance?

```
import wikipedia as wk
import time
from itertools import combinations
import string

def get_random_wikipedia_corpus(articles_number, verbose=False):
    contents = []
    i = 0
    while i < articles_number:
        try:
            page = wk.random()
            content = wk.page(page).content
            contents.append(content)
            i += 1
        except (wk.DisambiguationError, wk.PageError):
            pass
        time.sleep(1) # Avoid DDOSing Wikipedia :)
        if verbose:
            print(f"Iteration {i}, adding {page.title}")
    return ''.join(contents)

def all_ngrams(n):
    return (''.join(t) for t in combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, n))

def count_all(text, fragments, forbidden_counts=[]):
    return [(t, c/len(text)) for t in fragments if (c := text.count(t)) not in forbidden_counts]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = time.time()
    CORPUS_ARTICLES = 10
    
    corpus = get_random_wikipedia_corpus(CORPUS_ARTICLES).lower()
    corpus = ''.join(char for char in corpus if char in string.ascii_lowercase)
    
    print(time.time() - s, len(corpus))
    
    onegrams = all_ngrams(1)
    bigrams = all_ngrams(2)
    trigrams = all_ngrams(3)
    quadrigrams = all_ngrams(4)
    
    onegrams_counts = count_all(corpus, onegrams, (0, 1))
    bigrams_counts = count_all(corpus, bigrams, (0, 1))
    trigrams_counts = count_all(corpus, trigrams, (0, 1))
    quadrigrams_counts = count_all(corpus, quadrigrams, (0, 1))
    
    onegrams_counts.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
    bigrams_counts.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
    trigrams_counts.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
    quadrigrams_counts.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
    
    print(onegrams_counts)
    print(bigrams_counts)
    print(trigrams_counts)
    print(quadrigrams_counts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose an optimization based on the `multiprocessing` module,
to parallelize the requests. Unfortunately, if you want to get the results
as soon as possible, you will have to "DDOS" Wikipedia at some point,
and the `sleep` needs to be removed.

### Some notes and suggestions

- In the following piece of code, the `page` variable might not be defined in the `print`,
  the `pass` statement should probably be replaced by a `continue`:

```py
try:
    page = wk.random()
    ...
except (wk.DisambiguationError, wk.PageError):
    pass  # <- continue?
time.sleep(1) # Avoid DDOSing Wikipedia :)
if verbose:
    print(f"Iteration {i}, adding {page.title}")
```

(It seems that `page.title` is a method and not a property or an attribute in
the version of the `wikipedia` package I use (1.4.0), so it needs to be called
in order to display it correctly)

- The default value of the `forbidden_counts` argument of the `count_all` function
  should be an empty tuple instead of an empty list, as it is immutable, and it
  would be more consistent with the parameters you send when using this function.
- You could add a `main` function
- To handle the different sizes of "n-grams" and to avoid code duplication, a for loop
  wouldn't be more appropriate?

### Optimization part

In this proposed solution, a new function has been extracted from the
`get_random_wikipedia_corpus` function. This new function requests exactly one
valid article. The `get_random_wikipedia_corpus` only calls it multiple times
by using a `multithreading.Pool` object. Here is the solution with the suggestions:

```py
import multiprocessing
import string
import time
from itertools import combinations, repeat

import wikipedia as wk

CORPUS_ARTICLES = 10


def get_random_wikipedia_article(iteration: int, verbose: False) -> str:
    while True:
        page = wk.random()
        try:
            content = wk.page(page).content
        except (wk.DisambiguationError, wk.PageError):
            continue
        if verbose:
            print(f"Request {iteration}, adding '{page.title()}'")
        return content


def get_random_wikipedia_corpus(articles_number, verbose=False):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    return ''.join(pool.starmap(get_random_wikipedia_article, zip(range(articles_number), repeat(verbose))))


def all_ngrams(n):
    return (''.join(t) for t in combinations(string.ascii_lowercase, n))


def count_all(text, fragments, forbidden_counts=()):
    return [(t, c / len(text)) for t in fragments if (c := text.count(t)) not in forbidden_counts]


def main():
    s = time.time()
    corpus = get_random_wikipedia_corpus(CORPUS_ARTICLES, verbose=True).lower()
    corpus = ''.join(char for char in corpus if char in string.ascii_lowercase)

    print(time.time() - s, len(corpus))

    for letter_count in (1, 2, 3, 4):
        ngrams = all_ngrams(letter_count)
        ngrams_counts = count_all(corpus, ngrams, (0, 1))
        ngrams_counts.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
        print(ngrams_counts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Displayed metrics before optimization: 31.928 seconds for 30287 characters
- Displayed metrics after optimization: 2.154 seconds for 11948 characters

It would be more meaningful to compare those durations for the same requested pages.

Comment: Very very interesting, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I have a doubt about     `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(articles_number)` because it can build a really huge number of workers if the article number is high, it crashes for me for 1000 articles, with the cryptic error: https://pastebin.com/ed0aqC1i  maybe the number of workers should be equal to the number of virtual cores in the cpu for more stability right?

Comment: @Caridorc Indeed, `articles_number` can be removed: `pool = multiprocessing.Pool()`. The default value of the `processes` parameter of the [`Pool` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) is precisely the CPU count. I'll modify my answer.